# keep only wanted elements in xml with the given list of xpath

Tags: java, xml, dom, xslt, xpath

I have some complex xml structure. Some times i want to keep only the elements match my runtime list of xpath entries.

Sample xml

---

```
 <Employee>
    <Address>
        <addressLine1>Dummy Line 1</addressLine1>
        <zip>535270</zip>
    </Address>
    <Department>
        <id>102</id>
        <name>development</name>
    </Department
</Employee>
```

---

Sample xpath entries can be some time like

```
//Employee/Address
//Employee/Department/
//Employee/Department/name
```

In the above xpath if you observe we have Department and Name inside department then in that case I can ignore Department.Also above xpath entries can be as below too

```
//Employee/Address
//Employee/Department/name
```

Resultant xml i want as below

```
<Employee>
    <Address>
        <addressLine1>Dummy Line 1</addressLine1>
        <zip>535270</zip>
    </Address>
    <Department>
        <name>development</name>
    </Department
</Employee>
```

I realized I can achieve this through xslt. So I want the xslt for this kind of generic requirement. Also my current code is in java. Is there any better alternative in java??

Comment: "*I realized I can achieve this through xslt.*" Not easily, though, if the paths are passed **as strings** at runtime.

Comment: Can you explain in more details why `addressLine` and `zip` appear in the output although there is not path matching them? Why is `id` dropped but `zip` is not?

Comment: addressLine and zip are appearing because Address is exist and no other exclusions exist

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I do not fully understand your requirements, but what I do see is that:

- You have a set of XPath
- You seem to want to get the union of these XPath statements if applied to your input document
- Duplicates removed (just like XPath union expression)
- Some magic about certain elements that may appear even if they are not in the XPath statement list.

My original reflex was: use `xsl:evaluate`, but considering you are rooting all your XPath expressions, this may not give you the results you want. Also, it requires an XSLT 3.0 processor.

With XSLT 2.0, you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" 
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="patterns" as="xs:string*">
        <xsl:sequence select="(
            'foo/bar',
            'foo/test',
            'foo/bar/zed')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="node()[true() = (
        for $p in $patterns 
        return ends-with(
            string-join(current()/ancestor-or-self::*/name(), 
            '/'), $p))]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is just meant to get you started, it is not meant as a full-fledged solution. It matches XPath of the production `//QName/QName`, like the one in your example. I removed the trailing `//`, and simply match when the current path matches any of the paths (taking into account an implicit descendent-or-self, as in your example).

You probably want to wrap the for-expression in a function and call the function to map the concatenation of the current path to any of your paths in your list.

In its current form, you will also need to supply the paths leading up to a deeper path, or you will have to implement an [`fn:snapshot`-like function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-snapshot) to copy the ancestor nodes as well.

Anyway, I think this is a simple enough approach to mimic not necessarily `xsl:evaluate`, but mimic pattern matching based on a path, as your question seems to imply.

Comment: With this i am getting only leaf elements

Comment: @mohan, that's why I wrote _"In its current form, you will also need to supply the paths leading up to a deeper path, or you will have to implement an fn:snapshot-like function to copy the ancestor nodes as well."_. This is natural, because you cannot match what you don't know (the ancestors do not match the patterns, until at a deeper level).